# How to run eb deploy for different environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have elasticbeanstalk setup with different environments. Whenever I run `eb deploy` within the eb cli, it will always run for the original environment I set it up on `project-dev`.

Now, I want to deploy to a new environment that I created called `project-stage`, but I do not know how to switch to that environment to run `eb deploy`.

I read through the AWS documentation with no luck. I also tried experimenting with adding things like `eb deploy -project-dev`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eb deploy environment-name
```

In your case, try `eb deploy project-stage`

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html

Comment: thank you! for some reason, I thought there had to be a - in front of the command